# How to filter prefix and trim words from a string with JavaScript (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, string, filter, split, prefix

I have never been good with string manipulation and I am now stuck. So the long string has the following:

```
[desktop-detected display-settings  main-boxed  pace-done header-function-fixed nav-function-fixed nav-function-hidden nav-function-minify mod-sound mod-font]
```

I want to filter and keep the string with the nav-*, header-*, and mod-* prefixes, so the cleaned up string should look like:

```
[header-function-fixed nav-function-fixed nav-function-hidden nav-function-minify mod-sound mod-font]
```

I have no idea how to start, completely clueless...

Comment: If you've tried something, add the code.

Comment: Hi, I have not tried anything as I do not know javascript that well, its jquery what I am mostly familiar with.

Comment: Okay, if you know a way in jQuery add that if not atleast add the steps/algorithm you'll follow to solve problem in hand.

Comment: Here you go, `split` by space, `filter` words that starts with any of those conditions, `join` them by space.

Comment: how do I write that in javascript sequence? An example would be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

split, filter, and join

```
var result = '[' + string.split(/[^\w-]+/).filter(function(item) {
    return /^(nav|header|mod)-/i.test(item);
}).join(' ') + ']';
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/c3nff3p6/2/**

`/[^\w-]+/` is splitting the phrase into an array by not matching words or dashes as the separator.

`/^(nav|header|mod)-/i` matches if the item starts with either of those values followed by dash, case insensitive.

Other solutions, thanks [@Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679440/how-to-filter-prefix-and-trim-words-from-a-string-with-javascript-not-jquery/35679520?noredirect=1#comment59037142_35679520).

```
'[' + string.slice(1, -1).split(/\s+/).filter(str => /^(nav|header|mod)-/.test(str)).join(' ') + ']'
```

using match

```
'[' + string.slice(1, -1).match(/\b(nav|header|mod)-\S*/g).join(' ') + ']'
```

Comment: [give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679440/how-to-filter-prefix-and-trim-words-from-a-string-with-javascript-not-jquery#comment59036985_35679440)

Comment: Thanks Moogs! 

@Tushar, if I wanted to learn how to catch fish I would go to a fishing school. I was looking for a solution quickly as possible. Not everyone wants to learn how to catch a fish ;)

Comment: @Tushar great suggestion

Comment: @Moogs No prob. You can also make the code short by using ES6's Arrow functions which is widely supported. Here's mine `'[' + string.slice(1, -1).split(/\s+/).filter(str => /^(nav|header|mod)-/.test(str)).join(' ') + ']'`

Comment: Another one `'[' + string.match(/\b(nav|header|mod)-\S*/g).join(' ') + ']'`

Comment: @Tushar Maybe add those as answers, those are really good improvements.

Comment: Nah, feel free to add in your answer